# Hi i need to know what I am doing wrong here

Tags: javascript, object

```
{
    "messages": [{
        "msgFrom": "13223821242",
        "msgBody": "Hi there"
    }, {
        "msgFrom": "Bill",
        "msgBody": "Hello!"
    }]
}


var loop = () => {
  var arr = []
  for (var i = 0 ; i<messages.length; i ++) {
    arr.push(messages[1])
  }
  return loop()
  console.log(arr)
}
```

I need to iterate through this object and get only the messages pushed into the new array

same

Comment: is this arr.push(messages[1]) ? or arr.push(messages[i]) ??

Answer (score 1):

`arr.push(messages[1])`

1 should be i, you're grabbing the same index every time

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues

assuming the object to have a variable `obj`

```
var loop = () => {
  var arr = []
  for (var i = 0 ; i< obj.messages.length; i ++) { //messages is a key of an object, so messages is undefined, it should be obj.messages.
    arr.push(messages[i]) //wrong index, you should push `i` and not 1
  }
  return arr; // loop() is a function, causing endless recursion, causing stack overflow!
  console.log(arr) // will never print since function already returns!; move before return if you want it to print
}
```

Comment: sure @rashmedo :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this wrong, but your code is so messed up in different places, that I'd suggest you take another look at the absolute basics of JavaScript.

1. This is not valid JS syntax. It's basically an object that is never assigned to a variable.

```
{
    "messages": [{
        "msgFrom": "13223821242",
        "msgBody": "Hi there"
    }, {
        "msgFrom": "Bill",
        "msgBody": "Hello!"
    }]
}
```

Remove the outer curly brackets and use `var messages = [...]` to set the array as a variable `messages`.

```
var messages = [{
    "msgFrom": "13223821242",
    "msgBody": "Hi there"
}, {
    "msgFrom": "Bill",
    "msgBody": "Hello!"
}]
```

2. You are never calling the anonymous arrow function that `loop` is a reference to. Call it via `loop()`.
3. this will result in an endless loop, as your return value is actually a function call, calling the referenced function again and again.
4. You return from your function before the `console.log()` is ever reached, so nothing will be logged.
5. You should push `messages[i]`, as `messages[1]` is always pushing the second element (JS indexes are zero-based)

To wrap it all up, here's the cleaned and running code (which is essentially doing nothing, as it just copies all elements from one array to another):

```js
var messages = [{
  "msgFrom": "13223821242",
  "msgBody": "Hi there"
}, {
  "msgFrom": "Bill",
  "msgBody": "Hello!"
}];


var loop = () => {
  var arr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    arr.push(messages[i])
  }
  // return loop()
  console.log(arr)
}

loop();
```

Comment: Thank you Constantin for the detailed information. I copied the object from a sample online, didnt realize that would be wrong too :)  but thank you again for your help, greatly appreciate it. If you could also suggest a place where I can brush up my Object skills .. greatly appreciated

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer and/or upvote it as you see fit! I'm afraid I can't really name a single source for beginners. I myself started learning from a book at first more than two decades ago, and while today there are so many great resources online, it couldn't hurt to get a well rated one. Also just start to work on projects that are interesting to you and learn by debugging and solving one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use destructuring, it's short and simple.

```
var obj = { "messages": [
        {
            "msgFrom": "13223821242",
            "msgBody": "Hi there"
        }, {
            "msgFrom": "Bill",
            "msgBody": "Hello!"
        }
    ]
};

var arr = [...obj.messages];
console.log(arr);
```